# Looking for a standard mathematical function that returns 0 if x = 0 and a constant k when x <> 0

Tags: math

I am looking for a standard mathematical function f(x) that returns 0 if x = 0 and that returns a constant k when x is different from 0.
I tried the elevator function but it does not respond to my request. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `f(x) = abs(signum(x) * k) `

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming or software development question, so it's likely to be closed as off-topic on this site. But for what it's worth, in signal processing you'd often see this expressed as `k * (1 - delta(x))` where `delta` is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) / unit sample function.